# Access 2013: Check if a value is present in another table

Tags: validation, ms-access, reference, sql-update, relational-database

I've just discovered Access, having always been an Excel/VBA man... and now I've hit a roadblock!

I'm building an inventory database for my employer. I have 2 tables, one containing one column of 'stockID's (lets call this table 'tblWarehouse'), and another containing two columns: a column of 'orderID's and a column of 'stockID's (lets call this table 'tblOrders'). (For the sake of this question, lets disregard things like quantity, price etc)

We don't keep all the goods we sell in our own warehouse, some are sourced directly from the manufacturer to the customer, which means that not all tblOrders!stockID will be present in the list tblWarehouse!stockID. I need to find out when this is the case!

I want to create a third column in tblOrders containing a dummy variable = 1 if that particular item is in our warehouse. In other words, I want to create a calculated column = 1 if tblOrders!stockID can be found in tblWarehouse!stockID. Can this be done?

I've found that I can't reference another table directly, so I've been trying my hand at queries, user defined functions and relationships, but to no avail. I've also been having trouble with the Access-lingo and veritable forest of different places to input seemingly the same expressions... so please, if u have an answer for me, be sure to specify where things are located!

Much obliged!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking the two tables in a query using an inner join, only order records having at least one stock entry will be included in the result. In order to include those with no stock entry at all, create a left outer join.

```
SELECT O.OrderID, IIf(IsNull(MAX(W.StockID)), 0, 1) AS StockAvailable
FROM
    tblOrder O
    LEFT JOIN tblWarehouse W
        ON O.StockID = W.StockID
GROUP BY O.OrderID
```

You can also determin the join type in the query designer by right clicking a relation line and selecting "Join Properties" and then select "Include ALL records from `tblOrders` ...". You can make a grouping query by clicking the big Sigma-symbol in the symbol list.